# why when a circular superconductor cooled has magnetic filed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, critical-phenomena

i see in videos youtube that when a circular cooled about 200 kelvin it has some magnetic field around it,i think this Meissner  effect is called ,

my question is how QM describe it??it is really strang.
thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

the magnetic field is due to meissner effect.
it states that when a superconductor transitions from its superconducting state to normal state it excludes the magnetic effect form its sides. i.e. there are no magnetic fiels left inside of it.